# The Search for Earth Science Forums

Tags: science-based, worldbuilding-process, worldbuilding-resources

Finding online forums on the really big picture of worldbuilding--geography, geology, climatology, meteorology, ecology, glaciology--has proven to be very tedious with very few rewards.  It is crucial for me that before I make any embellishments set in my fictional world, I need to create a believable alternate Earth *first.*  (Magic, fantasy and mythology count as embellishments.)

Do you know any discussion forums online that allow hard-science on speculative scenarios of the earth-science disciplines listed above?

Comment: Sounds like most of that would be on-topic right here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the sciences are speculative by their very nature. Scientists must speculate in order to get somewhere with their discipline. So I'm sure they wouldn't mind a little off-topic discussion once in a while on their forums, especially if it was based on a realistic scenario.

So, my recommendations are thus:

1. This website (Physics Forums) is very sciencey. What I mean by that is it's very hard to see where some topics begin and end, but they're all there - variety, content, debate; you name it. [Click here](https://www.physicsforums.com/forums/earth.84/).
2. This website (The Science Forum) is also very sciencey but it also seems to be a bit informal, so I don't think you'd have trouble finding a place for your discussion. [Click here](http://www.thescienceforum.com/earth-sciences/).
3. This website (Space Battles) is definitely more your genre. However, I'm not sure what kind of questions would be allowed there given your criteria. It apparently has a [spin-off forum](http://forums.sufficientvelocity.com/), though. [Click here](https://forums.spacebattles.com/).
4. This site (SFWA) has a [list of blogs](http://www.sfwa.org/other-resources/for-authors/information-center/) as well as blog posts and resources to help you find your ideal world. [Click here](http://www.sfwa.org/).
5. This website (Joseph Shoer) might have some tips for you, or even the guy himself. He's quite the fictional map enthusiast. [Click here](http://www.josephshoer.com/index.html).

If you need anything else, let me know.

Comment: Where do I go on numbers 4 and 5 to post threads and questions?

Comment: Why include the Physics Forum?